# Customizing SWReveal View Controller Slide out Menu icons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swrevealviewcontroller

I am creating a slideoutmenu using the `SWRevealViewController` Library, and I am having trouble customizing the menuButtons in tableView, to change whenever a user taps on one of the buttons. So the user will tap on a button from the slide out menu, and it will change to an alternate image with inverted colors. (Like what most slideoutMenus have) However I am having trouble. The image that was supposed to change does not change, but the image that it was supposed to change to appears behind it and slightly larger, even though they are supposed to be the same size.

The button is an outlet named: `homeButtonIcon`(default image being a white home icon) and it will change to an image named “`blueHomeIconImproved`” (blue home icon)

What I have done is this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.homeButtonIcon.frame.size)
UIImage(named: "blueHomeIconImproved")?.draw(in: self.homeButtonIcon.bounds)

var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

self.homeButtonIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
```

And interestingly what happens is this.

[image]

Anybody have a fix to this? What would you do to make the images alternate properly?